# Parallel.ForEach vs AsParallel().ForAll

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I have a huge collection which I would like to process each of the object in a parallel fashion.  Doing the same synchronously typically involves a simple "foreach".

Just wondering, what to use in my scenario i.e., either Parallel.ForEach or MyCollection.AsParallel().ForAll().

Can you shed me some light on benefits of using the one vs the other.

Comment: This seems related; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270097/does-parallel-foreach-require-asparallel?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parallelizing a task using .AsParallel().ForAll or Parallel.ForEach performance issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415998/parallelizing-a-task-using-asparallel-forall-or-parallel-foreach-performance)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The way I see it, if all you want to do is to parallelize a `foreach`, you should use its parallel version, which is `Parallel.ForEach()`.

`ParallelEnumerable.ForAll()` is for the specific case where you have a LINQ query followed by a `foreach` and you want to parallelize both of them. So, what you do is that you parallelize the LINQ query by adding `AsParallel()` and then you parallelize the `foreach` by changing it into `ForAll()`.

Answer (score 10):

Time both and pick the winner.

I have found Parallel.ForEach to perform better in most delightfully parallel scenarios. It would seem that it uses a more advanced work balancing model. PLINQ is primarily aimed at parallelising queries.

Answer (score 4):

My 2 cents:

With `ForAll` you can specify the desired level of parallelism using the `WithDegreeOfParallelism` extension method.

With `ForEach` you can only limit the maximum level.

Basically, you can force `ForAll` to use more threads.

Comment: This makes no sense. The options to apply parallelism limits for `ForAll` and `ForEach` are exactly the same. What makes you think they are different?