# C# Splitting loop on multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a task that essentially loops through a collection and does an operation on them in pairs (for int i = 0; i < limit; i+=2 etc.) And so, most suggestions I see on threading loops use some sort of foreach mechanism. But that seems a bit tricky to me, seeing as how I use this approach of operating in pairs.

So what I would want to do is essentially replace:

```
DoOperation(list.Take(numberToProcess));
```

with

```
Thread lowerHalf = new Thread(() => => DoOperation(list.Take(numberToProcess/2)));

Thread lowerHalf = new Thread(() => => DoOperation(list.getRange(numberToProcess/2, numberToProcess));

lowerHalf.Start();
upperHalf.Start();
```

And this seems to get the work done, but it's VERY slow. Every iteration is slower than the previous one, and when I debug, the Thread view shows a growing list of Threads.

But I was under the impression that Threads terminated themselves upon completion? And yes, the threads do complete. The DoOperation() method is pretty much just a for loop.

So what am I not understanding here?

Comment: You could just do .Take(halfCount) for the lower half, then .Skip(halfCount) on the upper half.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Parallel.For](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713%28v=vs.110%29.aspx&ei=a4CUU6KnDsa9uATqy4CQDw&usg=AFQjCNHaWV1HguswFA5NCJ2e3Pu16IuO7w&sig2=E_fjdW-zxU0qTaYsYvRKSw&bvm=bv.68445247,d.c2E) It will save lot of work.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. I try to run a loop that would trigger this threading behaviour 18 times, but after 1-7 (very fast) runs, the program seems to be stuck somewhere.

Comment: Seriously, this x 100000

Answer (score 2):

To explain pranitkothari's answer a little bit more and give a different example you can use

```
list.AsParallel().ForAll(delegate([ListContainingType] item) {
    // do stuff to a single item here (whatever is done in DoOperation() in your code
    // except applied to a single item rather than several)
});
```

For instance, if I had a list string, it would be

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
list.AsParallel().ForAll(delegate(String item) {
    // do stuff to a single item here (whatever is done in DoOperation() in your code
    // except applied to a single item rather than several)
});
```

This will let you perform an operation for each item in the list on a separate thread. It's simpler in that it handles all the "multi-threadedness" for you.

[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920693/parallel-foreach-vs-asparallel-forall) is a good post that explains one of the differences in them

Comment: No luck so far with this approach. Lots of squiggly red lines. It says the type for the argument to the ForAll() call cannot be inferred. Is it because it is a custom object and not a primitive?

Comment: That shouldn't matter, as long as you replace `[ListContainingType]` with the type that is contained in the list, then it should work.

Comment: I did that. But don't have the code available to me at the moment. Will have a look later on. Maybe I made some other silly mistake.

Comment: Gotcha, when you get it, go ahead and update your question with what you've tried so we can see what exactly is happening.